# Extract App Version from versions.sbt through Command line

Tags: jenkins, playframework, sbt

Is there a way / command - I can extract an App version from a versions.sbt file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two ways to do this:

- ask sbt for the app version, this will work with any sbt project:

  sbt 'show version' | tail -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f2
- parse the `version.sbt` file:

  cat version.sbt | cut -d '"' -f2